# list indices must be integers or slices, not str GOOGLE COLAB

Tags: python, dataset

I have some trouble here while extracting some datasets.

```
app_reviews = []
for ap in tqdm(app_packages):
  for score in range(1, 6):
    for sort_order in [Sort.MOST_RELEVANT, Sort.NEWEST]:
      rvs= reviews(
          ap,
          lang='en',
          country='id',
          sort=sort_order,
          count=200000 if score == 3 else 100000,
          filter_score_with=score
      )
      for r in rvs:
        r['sortorder'] = 'most_relevant' if sort_order == Sort.MOST_RELEVANT else 'newest'
        r['appId'] = ap
      app_reviews.extend(rvs)
```

and the error code:

```
TypeError           

                  
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-43-35585cde036b> in <module>()
     14 
     15       for r in rvs:
---> 16         r['sortorder'] = 'most_relevant' if sort_order == Sort.MOST_RELEVANT else 'newest'
     17         r['appId'] = ap
     18       app_reviews.extend(rvs) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciate ;)

Comment: I think it's telling you that `r` is a list

Comment: Ya, `r` is a list, not a dictionary or something dictionary-like. You can't index a list with a string, as the error mentions. Double check your data.